# Fastlane upload fails: An attribute value is not acceptable for the current resource state. - The attribute 'versionString' can not be modified

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I am trying to push a new build to the appstore.
But my fastlane build failed with this error message:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/api_client.rb:199:in
> `handle_response': [!] An attribute value is not acceptable for the
> current resource state. - The attribute 'versionString' can not be
> modified. - /data/attributes/versionString
> (Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse)

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new release build to the App Store"
  lane :Runner do
  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
  build_app(scheme: "Runner", silent: true)
  upload_to_app_store
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that that app isn't approved and released for the appstore yet.
So I can only upload it to TestFlight.

I needed to use [upload_to_testflight](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/) fastlane

So the whole script in the Fastfile looks like:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new release build to the App Store"
  lane :Runner do
  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
  build_app(scheme: "Runner", silent: true)
  upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```